# How to set the location in the iOS simulator without writing code?

Tags: ios, gps, ios-simulator, core-location

My problem was how to set the gps location of my app when running in the iOS simulator

The home screen in my app displays sunrise and sunset times based on gps location and I wanted a screen shot with sensible values - I'm in the UK and the sunrise times were showing UK times for American sunrise and sunset.

As it is on the launch screen one solution, going to Debug -> Simulate Location, is too late for me.

Took me a while to work out and I wasn't finding the answer when I searched here (maybe not asking the question the right way . So I'm going to answer my own question below in the hope it stops someone else wasting their time

Comment: would any of the down voters here like to share why they thought this question was worth down voting. I wasted a couple of hours on it and thought it might be useful for someone else in my position. it also raised info from RobP about GPX files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add a .GPX file to your project, and use XCode's location simulation feature. You can set up the location simulation as part of your scheme, so it's in place at launch time.
Look under Edit Scheme, select "Run" at left, go to Options tab.

Comment: No need for adding a GPX file. you can just set the location from the, admittedly limited, range of choices there. I just needed something in the same country so the london one worked for me.

Comment: Well sure, if one of the handful of built-in locations works, so much the better. The important part was that you can set up location simulation as part of a Run scheme.

Comment: cheers Rob, I've not looked at .GPX file. I'm presuming that a .GPX file would contain a GPS data for a specific location ?

Comment: yes it's a simple XML file which can contain any points you not, or indeed, a series of points, so that you can simulate the device moving over a given path. You can export them after drawing in Bing maps or Google earth, record them with handheld GPS devices or mobile apps like Motion-X, and so on.

Comment: yw; and I meant points you want, not points you not. Coffee sinking in now... (I still think it's going to save you lots of time in the long run to make one or more schemes to do this than to click the little arrow in the debug area on each run..)

Comment: I just needed one location that made my sunrise sunset times show the right local time for a publicity shot. I'm done now but point taken about multiple scheme.

Comment: Edit Scheme is under "Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme" or `CMD+Shift+,`

Answer (score 9):

You can Simulate Location Position with Xcode:

[image]

From here, if you stops the build sometimes is returning to **Don't Simulate Location**.

However, clicking **Run**, while the app is running, Xcode asks you to **Stop** and Run, click Stop and the Simulator runs again the build. This time, for sure, with your Location.

Comment: OP said:
As it is on the launch screen one solution, going to Debug -> Simulate Location, is too late for me.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I wanted coming from google, even if it doesn't answer OP's question

Answer (score 5):

My solution turned out to be easy

Click on the name of the project (next to the run and stop buttons in the top left of the Xcode screen) and select Edit Scheme.

Go to the options pane.

The first thing is Core Location allow Location simulation. Then below that set Default Location to the one you want.

Done

Comment: not sure why two people down voted my solution which worked perfectly for my needs and my stated problem

Comment: They probably thought you copied the other answers although it looks like the three of you answered almost simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

The **EASIEST** way is to go to the debug tab of the simultor :

[image]

then go to the location button, and you can set the location you want :

[image]

Comment: The menu has been moved to `Features` Tab